# Laravel - How to detach with condition?

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship, where-clause

I want to detach values from a model based on a condition. I want to detach all people from the organization whose type is 3, which are workers. But when I try to do so, it detaches all people, not taking into account the where condition.

here are my relationships:

Class: Organization

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(People::class, 'organization_people')
}

public function workers()
{
    return $this->people()->where('type', 3); //returns all workers
}

public function detachWorkers()
{
    $this->workers()->detach(); // this detaches all people, I want it to detach only workers
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(People::class, 'organization_people')
}

public function workers()
{
    return $this->people()->where('type', 3);
}

public function detachWorkers()
{
    $this->people()->detach($this->workers); 
}
```

IIUC Laravel will not append that `where` contstraint onto the `detach`. Howerver, it will append any contstraints that you place on the pivot table directly, such as `$this->people()->wherePivot('type', 3);` assuming that you have a `type` column on the pivot table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it give me an error saying "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string". I fixed it by writing: $this->people()->detach($this->people->where('type', 3); I did not call the method, but the property people.